# Sum Mysql table Column Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name subscriber. There are two column name Hours and NewHr, there are lot of data posted into these two column. I want subtract total value of Hours column and NewHr column. Here i am using the following code. But it only subtract the first value of Hours and First value of NewHr from the column.

```
$Uid=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE    Uid='$_SESSION[UniqId]'"));
$first_number = ($Uid['Hours']);
$second_number = ($Uid['NewHr']);     
$Balance_total = $first_number - $second_number;
```

Please tell me what code will i replace into the  $first_number = ***_*** and $second_number = **______** to subtract the total column value.

Comment: Add a structure sample of both columns, otherwise you'll might get incorrect solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data you gave this query should do the job:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Hours) - SUM(NewHr)
  FROM subscriber 
  WHERE    Uid='$_SESSION[UniqId]'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the difference of the total, then you can do it like this with a query itself

```
$result =mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Newhr) - SUM(Hours) as difference FROM subscriber WHERE Uid='$_SESSION[UniqId]'"));
$Balance_total = $result['difference'];
```